# How to parametrize table column creation with help of list?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I want to use a list with column names to generate CREATE TABLE `sql` script.

I want to create a function.

```
def create_table(column_names: List[str]):
    pass
```

Example:

```
Input ["col1", "col2", "colN"]
```

Output:

```
psycopg2.sql.SQL('''CREATE TABLE my_table (
        created_ts TIMESTAMPTZ,
        col1 BYTEA,
        col2 BYTEA,
        ...
        colN BYTEA''')
```

Finally I want to execute this SQL statement

I read about

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

columns = ["col1", "col2", "colN"]

stmt = sql.SQL('''CREATE TABLE my_table (
    created_ts TIMESTAMPTZ,
    {} BYTEA,
    {} BYTEA,
    {} BYTEA,
    ''').format(columns[0], columns[1], columns[2])
```

But problem is that number of columns may be different..

Answer (score 1):

Use `join()` to construct the SQL dynamically.

```
columns = ["col1", "col2", "colN"]

cols_sql = ', '.join(f'{col} BYTEA' for col in columns)
stmt = sql.SQL(f'''CREATE TABLE my_table (
    created_ts TIMESTAMPTZ,
    {cols}''')
```